# firefox debugger doesn't hit breakpoint except on original load

Tags: javascript, firebug

So I am I getting an error using tinyMCE but that isn't really the question here. I am trying to debug it using firebug and I am a little confused. I have a break point here. 
[image]

This breakpoint gets hit when the page loads but then although the error says it is on line 564 I never see it get hit again (even though I can click save over and over and get the same error). Is that because of the way that function gets created? clearly JQuery is creating some sort of object literal with a bunch of functions as the value of the variables like

```
var functions = { 
  func1: function() {...},
  func2: function() {...}
};
```

instead of saying

```
var myAwesomeFunction = function() { //do awesome };
```

I am not sure but if so how I can debug this?

Thanks

Comment: Just put the breakpoint on 564. 559 will not get hit when 564 is executed because it is an anonymous callback.

Comment: in the case where `window.execScript` exists, the script will evaluate to `window.execScript(data);` and never execute the function on line 564.

Comment: But I presume from the comment in the code that it isn't using execScript because I am not running IE, on top of that the error says the problem was on line 564 although I can't get the break point to hit there I think it's most certainly executing that and not window.execScript, or - I am nuts? That's possible too.